# How do I define my table owner/schema in my sequel class?

Tags: ruby, sequel

The table I'm trying to query is named is `cache.dashboardstats`

my model is:

```
class Dashboard < Sequel::Model(:dashboardstats)
 set_schema do
    set_primary_key :dashboardstatid
  end
end
```

This creates a `select * from "dashboardstats";`

How do I define the owner/schema of "cache" so that my query becomes:

`select * from cache."dashboardstats";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a double underscore inside a symbol, or one of the qualify methods to represent a qualified identifier:

```
:cache__dashboardstats
Sequel.qualify(:cache, :dashboardstats)
:dashboardstats.qualify(:cache)
```

You would use this in your model code like:

```
class Dashboard < Sequel::Model(:cache__dashboardstats)
end
```

Note that I left out your set_schema call.  You should never call set_schema unless you are calling create_table or a similar method, as otherwise it does nothing.  set_primary_key inside set_schema doesn't do what you think, and Sequel can usually determine the primary key correctly, so it's not normally specified manually.